# Laravel PDOException in Connector.php line 119: could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel

I know this question has been asked many times, but those solutions don't seem to work for me. This is because I am using Xampp for Linux, *not* Lampp. Therefore, ever time I want to artisan anything I have to alias the `php` to point to the one in Xampp, i.e. `alias php="/opt/lampp/bin/php"`, but today I've been met with a major stumbling block. I can't save anything to the database because of the above error. I think it roots to the Laravel not accessing the Xampp to do this. So can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Open your `php.ini` and uncomment the line that says: `extension=php_pdo_mysql` if you are using MySQL or the other extension that are listed after this option.

PS: **Do not forget to restart XAMPP.**

Answer (score -1):

We have the same problem, I uses ubuntu 16.04.1 amd64 and database xampp php version 7.0, And I uses MYSQL connection. it is ***

> PDOException connector.php line 119: Could not find driver

***. what error appears to me, However in a coincedence, I able to solve the problem by uncomenting the following :

**zend_extension=opcache.so**

**extension=php_mbstring.dll**

**extension=php_mysql.dll**

**extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll**

in the "**php.ini**" file, in folder "**/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini**"

Hope this will work on you! sorry for my bad english